# How do you query an object set and in that same query filter an attached entity collection?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework for the first time and noticed that the entities object returns entity collections.

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
db.Users; //Users is an ObjectSet<User>
User user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username == "test").First(); //Is this getting executed in the SQL or in memory?
user.Posts; //Posts is an EntityCollection<Post>
Post post = user.Posts.Where(x => x.PostID == "123").First(); //Is this getting executed in the SQL or in memory?
```

Do both ObjectSet and EntityCollection implement IQueryable? I am hoping they do so that I know the queries are getting executed at the data source and not in memory.

**EDIT:** So apparently EntityCollection does not while ObjectSet does. Does that mean I would be better off using this code?

```
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    User user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username == "test").First(); //Is this getting executed in the SQL or in memory?
    Post post = db.Posts.Where(x => (x.PostID == "123")&&(x.Username == user.Username)).First(); // Querying the object set instead of the entity collection.
```

Also, what is the difference between ObjectSet and EntityCollection? Shouldn't they be the same?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Sorry, I'm new to this. I'm trying to understand. Attached EntityCollections are lazy loaded, so if I access them then memory is populated with them. Rather than doing two querys to the object sets like in my last edit, I am curious if this query would be more what I was after:

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
User user = (from x in db.Users
             from y in x.Posts
             where x.Username == "test"
             where y.PostID == 123
             select x).First();
```

Comment: Anybody that answers this will have to do what you should have done instead of posting this question. Tip, F12 will take you to the definition of a property when the cursor is on the property name and to the type when the cursor is on the type.

Comment: You don't have to be a smartass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ObjectSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx) does implement `IQueryable<T>`, but [`EntityCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354106.aspx) does not.

The difference is that `ObjectSet<T>` is meant to be used for querying directly (which is why it does implement the interface).  `EntityCollection<T>`, on the other hand, is used for the "many" end of a result set, typically returned in a query done on an `ObjectSet<T>`.  As such, it impelments `IEnumerable<T>`, but not `IQueryable<T>` (as it's already the populated results of a query).

Comment: So then, when I query user.Posts I am querying an in-memory collection?

Comment: @Chevex: Exactly.  `db.Users.Where` does a query, which returns the user.  Since the user is returned, all of it's "Posts" have already been pulled across.

Comment: @Chevex: You'd need to push these into a single query, if you don't want to pull it local.

Comment: Wow, so every user object population pulls all that user's posts, whether or not I intend to access that collection? That's horrible.

Comment: @Chevex - That's not accurate. Related collections are either explicitly loaded (in the original query via Include()) or lazy loaded.

Comment: Ohhhh, so if I access the collection then it will populate the collection into memory, and then execute the query. Is that right?

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of how to populate my user object while also filtering the attached Posts entity collection to only include desired posts instead of ALL of that users posts?

Comment: @Chevex: You can't, really - you'd have to fetch the user, and then fetch the posts separately.  In order to assign the posts to a User object, it will always assign all of them...

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. So really, entity collections are only useful if you need to iterate over the entire collection. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I was almost ready to say yes, they both do. Luckily I check [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354106.aspx) first.

**EntityCollection does not implement IQueryable.**

As for the difference, `ObjectSet<TEntity>` represents the the objects generated from a table in a database. `EntityCollection<TEntity>` represents a collection of entity objects on the 'Many' side of One to Many or Many to Many relationship.

Comment: I was just writing up almost the same exact thing when I got the "orange someone else answered this question" bar. Seems like it should, but I guess not.

Comment: I agree, seems Entity Collections shouldn't be loaded right away. Does that mean every time a populate a user object I get all the posts too!!!??? That's horrible! That means one user query is querying all that user's posts even if I don't intend to access them. Lame.

Reconsidering entity framework now.